# How to hide bottom bar through adb shell command programmatically android 4.2+

Tags: android, shell, adb

To hide the bottom bar from tablet, I am trying to run this command through code

```
 try
    {

       Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui"});
       proc.waitFor();
    }
catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Then it's throwing exception

java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su, -c, service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui] Working Directory: null Environment: null

But when I am executing command through adb like "adb shell service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui" its working fine. I mean its hiding the bottom bar successfully. Can any one help about this issue ?

Comment: did you get any solution for this issue?